# Delete 2nd row from CSV file with a batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I just need to delete the second row from a csv file using a batch file. Its always going to be the second row, though the text could be different.

I keep finding answers, but it seems like they are always more complicated then what I would like to do

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read lines from input.csv
< input.csv (

   rem Read and copy the first line
   set /P "line="
   echo(!line!

   rem Just read the second line
   set /P "line="

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > output.csv
```

Comment: I like it.  +1.  I'd recommend leaving delayed expansion disabled until just before `echo(!line` to avoid clobbering exclamation marks in the data though.

Comment: @rojo: There are _not_ any possible problems related to delayed expansion in this code! **`;)`**

Comment: I guess you're right!  I didn't realize `set /P` behaved differently from `set` regarding delayed expansion.  Interesting!

Answer (score 2):

```js
@echo off & setlocal

>outfile.csv (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in (
        'findstr /n "^" infile.csv ^| findstr /v "^2:"'
    ) do echo(%%J
)
```

To follow the logic of this script, read it from the inside out.  The first `findstr` will read `infile.csv` and prepend line numbers to each line.  The piped second `findstr` command will exclude all lines beginning with `2:`.  The outer `for /F` will strip the prepended line numbers.  The whole thing is dumped to `outfile.csv`.