# batch replace line under line to find

Tags: batch-file, replace

I wish to replace a string, *(or append to one)*, in a text file.

There are many instances of that string in my file but I only wish to modify a single instance. To identify the line I know that it will always be found on the line below one which includes a unique string.

My thoughts are:

1. find line with unique string `" cargo_mass:"`
2. find line directly below it, containing non-unique string `" base_color:"`
3. replace line with txt `" base_color: (1, 1, 1)"`

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: You are supposed to provide your code, and ask for help with it when you come accross a problem, not list your requirements for somebody else to do the work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Thought I might try [Aacini's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167548/1683264) for a little practice.  See inline comments for explanation.  In the future, please show the efforts you have put into solving the problem on your own.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "txtfile=notes.txt"
set "search=cargo_mass:"
set "nextline=base_color: (1, 1, 1)"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // find number of line containing search string
for /f "delims=:" %%I in ('findstr /n /i "!search!" ^<"!txtfile!"') do set /a "num=%%I"

if not defined num ( echo(!search! not found in !txtfile! & goto :EOF )

rem // read txtfile
< "!txtfile!" (

    rem // from beginning to found line, output each line untouched
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%num%) do (
        set line=
        set /P "line="
        echo(!line!
    )

    rem // consume a line of input and output the replacement txt
    set /P "="
    echo(!nextline!

    rem // output the rest of the file
    findstr "^"

) > "~!txtfile!"

move /y "~!txtfile!" "!txtfile!"
```

Comment: The vars `txtfile,search and nextline` are all static throuhghout the batch - is there a reason to use `!` instead of `%` ? Albeit I know it doesn't harm using the `!`. +1

Comment: @LotPings In the `echo(!search! etc.` and `echo(!nextline!` lines, delaying expansion can prevent ampersands and other special characters from being evaluated.  Beyond that, my reasons involved a fair amount of laziness.  Delayed variables relieved me of the need to think of edge cases where percent variables might break.  I used them because I could.  (:

Comment: @LotPings, when delayed expansion is enabled, you are going to run into trouble if a strig contains literal `!` and you expand it using `%`...

Comment: This does not check whether the line after `cargo_mass:` actually contains `base_color:`; +1 though...